# JQuery UI Slide animation triggering the scrollbar to display during the animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use JQuery UI's slide animation to toggle a div.
When a link is clicked, the div slide in the page from the right (as seen in this fiddle).

```js
$("#toggle").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $("#slider").toggle("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#slider {
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #DDD;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="toggle">
    click me to slide
  </div>
  <div id="slider">
    Slidin' in & Slidin' out
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem I have is this scrollbar that appears during the animation, I don't want it to be displayed, like in [JQuery UI's website](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/show.html), they don't have this scrollbar issue and I don't know how they did it.

I would like to avoid wrapping `#slider` into another container if possible, and I can't set his parent to `overflow: hidden` neither at the moment.

Is there a simple way to fix this ?

Comment: Why can't you set `overflow: hidden` on the `body` element? -> `body { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: You could set `overflow-x: hidden` as soon as you click the element and remove it once the animation has finished, if you don't want to have it permantly set

Comment: I can't do this unfortunately, I need the overflow of the body to remain auto in order to have a scrollbar when it is necessary :/ hidden overflow wouldn't do it neither since it would also cut content (and desired) overflow for the animation duration. This issue is a tough one ^^' thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to set `overflow: hidden` on the `body` element. However, since you said that you can't do that, an alternative solution would be to animate the width of the element in order to make it appear like it is sliding in. In reality the width of the element is just increasing/decreasing from `0` and it is animated to make it look like it is sliding.

In jQuery you would do this with the `.animate()` method and you would set the value of `width` property to `'toggle'`.

```
$("#toggle").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();

  $("#slider").animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  }, 200);
});
```

In addition, you can also prevent the text from wrapping with `white-space: nowrap`.

See the full example below:

```js
$("#toggle").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  
  $("#slider").animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  }, 200);
});
```

```css
#toggle {
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#slider {
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #DDD;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="toggle">
    click me to slide
  </div>
  <div id="slider">
    Slidin' in & Slidin' out
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would go with that solution if it wasn't for the collapsing effect of the content during the animation, It doesn't look very good in my situation where there are forms, text and sometimes tables. Is there a way to correct this ?

Comment: @eloism - For text you could use `white-space: nowrap`, [see this example](https://jsfiddle.net/6udmxzb7/). That also seems to resolve the issue when a `table` is used as well: https://jsfiddle.net/LnL38282/

Comment: @eloism - I tried it with a few more elements and it seems to work. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/1wnppgg9/).